# can't get more than 1 attribute using ldap in php

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to get more than 1 attribute using ldap in PHP.
I'm using a class to do so.
the problem is that when I try to get 1 attribute - it is working, but when trying more than 1 - it fails and return null.
here is how I call the function :

```
$return  = $ldap->getAttribute('displayname,mail','cn=Jhon Doe');
```

and the function inside the class looks like this :

```
public function getAttribute($attr,$filter){
         $rObjs = preg_split("/,/",$attr);

        /* Execute the actual search on the directory */
        if($this->ldapResultset = @ldap_search($this->ldapResource, $this->GetldapDomain(), $filter, $rObjs)){
            $info = ldap_get_entries($this->ldapResource, $this->ldapResultset);
        }
        /* Validate we have a result that matters */
        if($info['count'] > 0){
            if(@$info[0][$attr]['count'] > 0){
                return $info[0][$attr];
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }   
    }
```

but if I do this :

```
$return  = $ldap->getAttribute('displayname','cn=Jhon Doe');
```

it is working..

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was here :

```
if(@$info[0][$attr]['count'] > 0){
```

$info has the correct information

Answer (score 0):

At that point the funtion tries to retrieve an array-element with key "displayname,mail" which does not exist. Therefore the function returns "false". It looks like the function doesn't handle multiple arguments really well.